# Matlab: create lines with equal physical length along each axis

Tags: matlab, vector-graphics

I want to make scale bars with ticks, and I want the ticks on the X and Y bars to have the same physical length, regardless of the relative lengths, dimensions, or "modes" of the axes (at least at the time the ticks are created). I was hoping that daspect() would give me the information I need for this, but daspect() seems to be mostly useless for interrogating aspect ratio. For instance, if I generate a plot that Matlab gives an XLim of [0 3.5] and a YLim of [0 1], then daspect() gives [3.5 1 ...] regardless of how I have the figure sized on the screen. That's obviously not accurate or helpful. Is there another function, or maybe a way to make daspect() give useful information without manipulating the plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

daspect() returns garbage on a typical plot. It's because of the stretch-to-fill feature, which distorts the plot to fill up the figure space, rendering the values in DataAspectRatio inaccurate. Instructions for turning off stretch-to-fill can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/daspect.html#bus0nbw).

I also found a workaround if you want to leave stretch-to-fit on, which is to temporarily set PlotBoxAspectRatioMode to 'manual,' which has the effect of changing the value of DataAspectRatio to match what is on screen.

```
figure;plot(0.1:0.1:pi,sin(0.1:0.1:pi))
pbaspect manual
val = daspect
pbaspect auto
```

Or a safer way to do it if you want a generally useful script (e.g. in case PlotBoxAspectRatioMode is already manual and you don't want to change that) would be:

```
pbaspectMode = get(gca,'PlotBoxAspectRatioMode');
pbaspect manual;
val = daspect;
set(gca,'PlotBoxAspectRatioMode',pbaspectMode);
```

I'm not sure whether this will have any intermittent or pernicious side effects, however.

According to The Mathworks support:

> The technique of setting bpaspect to manual and then back may be "safe" (although I wouldn't be surprised if there are side effects), but a better way is to divide:

```
real_daspect = daspect./pbaspect;
```